# Group values in sets without overlaping

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Having this data set:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `details` (
  id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `item` INT(6) NOT NULL,
  `dateOut` DATE,
  `dateIN` DATE
);

INSERT INTO details VALUES
  (1,1, '2020.04.11', '2020.04.11'),
  (2,1, '2020.04.12', '2020.04.12'),
  (3,1, '2020.04.13', '2020.03.11'),
  (4,1, '2020.04.13', '2020.04.13'),
  (5,1, '2020.04.14', '2020.03.11');
```

[fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4ezC266rmRJUznimSft6ny/1). 
Is it possible to get this result in mysql/php(laravel):

```
2020-04-11 => [id: 1,3,5]
2020.04.12 => [id: 2]
2020.04.13 => [id: 4]
```

Meaning where `dateIN <= min(dateOut)` group the values, then with the remaining values (remove the first group from the set) repeat.

So the first time min(dateOut) is `2020-04-11`. Ids: `1,3,5` have `dateIn` <= `2020-04-11` so I grouped them. Remove id `1,3,5` from the initial set.

Then on the remaining values min(dateOut) is `2020-04-12` and only Id: `2` has `dateIn` <= `2020-04-12`. Remove id `2`.

Then on the remaining values min(dateOut) is `2020-04-13` and only Id: `4` has `dateIn` <= `2020-04-13`. Remove id `4` and so on until all values are grouped.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be straightforward to filter this result in your application code...

```
SELECT x.*
     , GROUP_CONCAT(y.id ORDER BY y.id) canidiates
  FROM details x 
  JOIN details y   
    ON y.datein <= x.dateout 
 GROUP 
    BY x.id;
+----+------+------------+------------+------------+
| id | item | dateOut    | dateIN     | canidiates |
+----+------+------------+------------+------------+
|  1 |    1 | 2020-04-11 | 2020-04-11 | 1,3,5      |
|  2 |    1 | 2020-04-12 | 2020-04-12 | 1,2,3,5    |
|  3 |    1 | 2020-04-13 | 2020-03-11 | 1,2,3,4,5  |
|  4 |    1 | 2020-04-13 | 2020-04-13 | 1,2,3,4,5  |
|  5 |    1 | 2020-04-14 | 2020-03-11 | 1,2,3,4,5  |
+----+------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: I cannot figure out how to create a filter loop.

Comment: Well I might try to cobble something together, though it's not really my forte, but essentially you have two arrays; one that represents the current row, and one that represents cumulative (distinct) values from all previous rows. Then you're just looking at the difference between those arrays.